# Git gui clients on windows as nice as GitX on MacOS?

Tags: windows, git

Can someone suggest for me only one git gui client on windows that is the same as GitX on Mac? (nice, easy to use, wonderful interface, etc...)

I have tried some but I do not feel happy :p

Thank you

Comment: up to now, I am still not happy with any of the git clients for Windows.

Comment: Use git cola. It's the closest to gitx you can get and I really like it: https://git-cola.github.io/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do not know GitX, but [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) is a rich and user friendly gui for Windows. It has a stand-alone application, shell extensions and a Visual Studio (2005/2008/2010) plugin.

Answer (score 6):

SmartGit is better than GitX

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html

Answer (score 6):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is a nice git GUI for windows (but is not available for XP or Vista and some other old Windows versions.)

Also, you can find a list of git GUIs on the [official git website](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

Comment: if only git tower had a windows equivalent. All windows git gui clients are horrid

Comment: Not available on older versions of Windows.

Comment: SourceTree is a horrible mess of unstable code - manages to delete files when switching branches, fail merges due to "Permission denied" errors due to SourceTree having the file open (!!) and so on, highly NOT recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried TortoiseGit? It integrates very well with the shell (Windows Explorer). I personally also like QGit, don't know if it's available for Windows though.

Comment: I didn't have much luck with TortoiseGit - it seems to be a little unstable (the icon overlay never worked on my Win 7 machine). I ended up using SmartGit, which is built from the ground up for Git support, and it just worked with no issues.

Comment: The icon overlay feature in Windows is very limited (max of 15 overlays system-wide)... so if TortoiseGit is not your only overlay application, it just won't work.  You can hack this in the registry, but I wouldn't recommend it.  SmartGit was the way to go for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned yet are also gitk and Git Gui, included with the msysgit install package.

Here is the direct download link for [QGit for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qgit/files/qgit4_win_installer/2.3/qgit-2.3_win.exe/download), which was mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Try Smartgit. It's better.
http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html

Comment: +1 for SmartGit: It just works, no fuss, no hassles.

Comment: SmartGit was already mentioned before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383789/1127485

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using and liking [GitKraken](http://www.gitkraken.com/). It's cross platform across Windows, Mac & Linux and it has built-in support for GitHub and BitBucket as well as git-flow.

It's currently in open beta and free.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just found this client and trying to install it on a MacBook Pro with 10.11.3. Opened Finder, searched the download, pressed Space and Activate. Nothing happens. Any hint?